# Scilab: How to use of "lev" and "filter" to model AR1 processes?

Tags: model, signal-processing, scilab

I need to fit an AR1 model to a series of values. Reading Scilab documentation, I came up with the method in the example below (edited with new code and more complete results):

```
//Testing "filter" and "lev" function for AR1 model y(t) = 0.8*y(t-1) - v016.3
rand("seed", 0);
time = (1:128)';
y = rand(128,1, "normal");  //128 values of gaussian noise
A = [1];    //Coefficients of AR1 polinomial denominator: A(1)+A(2)*y(t-1)
B = [0, 0.8];  //Coefficients of AR1 polinomial numerator: B(1)+B(2)*y(t-1)
z = filter(B,A, y);    //AR1 process from series y
scf(0); clf(0);
 plot(time, y, "+");
 plot(time, z, "-k");
arc = lev(z);    //Calculates AR coefficients vith "lev"
arc = arc(1:2);
z_mod = filter(arc,1, y);   //Modeled series
plot(time, z_mod, "-g");
ar_norm = arc/arc(1);
z_mod2 = filter(ar_norm,1, y);    //Second modeled series from normalized coefficients
plot(time, z_mod2, "-r");
legend("y", "z", "z_mod", "z_mod2");
//End of Code
```

These are the results in graphical form.

[image]

And in numerical form:

```
  >B
   B  =

   0.    0.8  

-->arc
arc  =

2.51968    
- 5.4210567  

-->ar_norm
ar_norm  =

1.         
- 2.1514862
```

I would expect that the AR coefficients calculated with the Levinson method are at least close the the ones I input as `B`, but this is not the case. Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Your question is too vague as it is right now, and we can't help you. Can you tell us what a convincing result would be? What did you expect to get?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more precise.

Comment: @luispauloml Can you understand my problem now?

Comment: Yes, I think I can, but I don't have a solution to it, sorry...

Comment: That's too bad. What's more galling is that even by running the example code provided on Scilab's `lev` page, the results are nowhere near the input  AR coefficients.